# Selenium + IntelliJ: annoying warnings, how to fix them

Tags: java, selenium

I always get the following warnings when i ty to execute my code...
The code works but it is annoying and i would like to fix it!

```
1580642544984   mozrunner::runner   INFO    Running command: "/usr/lib/firefox/firefox" "-marionette" "-foreground" "-no-remote" "-profile" "/tmp/rust_mozprofilevW0se4"
1580642546026   addons.webextension.screenshots@mozilla.org WARN    Loading extension 'screenshots@mozilla.org': Reading manifest: Invalid host permission: resource://pdf.js/
1580642546027   addons.webextension.screenshots@mozilla.org WARN    Loading extension 'screenshots@mozilla.org': Reading manifest: Invalid host permission: about:reader*

(firefox:7348): Gtk-WARNING **: 12:22:26.596: Theme parsing error: <data>:1:34: Expected ')' in color definition

(firefox:7348): Gtk-WARNING **: 12:22:26.596: Theme parsing error: <data>:1:77: Expected ')' in color definition
1580642549203   Marionette  INFO    Listening on port 43209
1580642549310   Marionette  WARN    TLS certificate errors will be ignored for this session
Feb. 02, 2020 12:22:29 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
```

And here the code:

```
package com.Selenium_intelliJ;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class Main {

    public static void search(WebDriver obj, String search){

        obj.findElement(By.name("q")).sendKeys(search);
        obj.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div/div[3]/form/div[2]/div[1]/div[3]/center/input[1]")).submit();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "/home/josef/Java/geckodriver/geckodriver");
        WebDriver obj = new FirefoxDriver();
        obj.get("https://www.google.com/xhtml");
        search(obj, "test");

    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Most of them come from Geckodriver not Selenium and definitely not from your IDE.

Comment: Are you using ubuntu version 18?

Comment: I’ve switched to chrome without geckodriver and the errors still appear. Im on Linux Mint 19.1